TypeScript / NextJS / Redux toolkit issue - useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>(); Not a function
I am trying to dive deep into learning Redux-Toolkit and I am running into dispatch errors.
authSlice.ts
import { createAppSlice } from "@/lib/createAppSlice";
import type { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface IAuthState {
  authState: boolean;
}

const initialState: IAuthState = {
  authState: false,
};

export const authSlice = createAppSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAuthState: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.authState = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setAuthState } = authSlice.actions;
export const authReducer = authSlice.reducer;

store.ts
import type { Action, ThunkAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineSlices, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { counterSlice } from "./features/counter/counterSlice";
import { quotesApiSlice } from "./features/quotes/quotesApiSlice";
import { authSlice } from "./features/auth/authSlice";

const rootReducer = combineSlices(counterSlice, quotesApiSlice, authSlice);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

export const makeStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
      return getDefaultMiddleware().concat(quotesApiSlice.middleware);
    },
  });
};

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore["dispatch"];
export type AppThunk<ThunkReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ThunkReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action
>;

hooks.ts
// This file serves as a central hub for re-exporting pre-typed Redux hooks.
import { useDispatch, useSelector, useStore } from "react-redux";
import type { AppDispatch, AppStore, RootState } from "./store";

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>();
export const useAppStore = useStore.withTypes<AppStore>();

authUpdater.tsx
This is where the dispatch is being called.
import React from "react";
import { setAuthState } from "@/lib/features/auth/authSlice";
import { useAppDispatch } from "@/lib/hooks";

export const AuthUpdater = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(setAuthState(true))}>Log in</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(setAuthState(false))}>Log out</button>
    </div>
  );
};

I am not sure why the dispatch is throwing me errors, such as follows:

react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useDispatch.withTypes is not a function


Got the same error using redux-toolkit with Next.js and TypeScript. Resolved the issue by using the same versions for @reduxjs/toolkit and react-redux lib in my package.json as those specified in the package.json of the Vercel Next.js with Redux Toolkit example and adding use client at top of .tsx file/component.

Need to add "use client", thanks

I believe the issue you are running into here is the way you are creating the hooks. I do see where you found this method within the react-redux documentation and I think you may want to assure that your react-redux version is current, however personally I do not have experience using this way of declaring the hooks.
The react-redux version you need at minimum is v9.1.0 for the .withTypes.
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
export const useAppStore: () => AppStore = useStore;

Above is the version I typically use, let me know if you run into any issues or if there is anything I can clarify.
Update: I believe the issue is within the following
export type AppDispatch = AppStore["dispatch"];

Instead of what you currentyl have for the store I would change it to this.
export const makeStore = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(quotesApiSlice.middleware),
  });

This way makeStore is of type Store instead of type () => (Store). With this the following should fix your problem(hopefully).
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;


Hi, thank you for your answer. The strange thing is that I am using the 'useDispatch,AppSelector, and useAppstore in a counter (from the premade template) and it works fine. I only run into this issue when I try using my custom slice (reducer). I am going through the docs again now so hopefully I can find the answer

Oh, I did see something there that was a bit confusing, what is this createAppSlice function and where is it coming from?

It is basically coming from the @reduxjs/toolkit package.  its a function made in another file using the 'buildCreateSlice' function and uses the asyncThunkCreator. its used to create a slice with async thunks.

i'll edit the code for the createAppSlice into my post, but it seems bugged right now and isn't letting me edit

@nKc Some updates that I think should solve the problem
